# Disable default keybinding of JTable for a single column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm using autocomplete in my `JTable` column which uses the <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> key to move so as the `JTable` how can I disable up and down keybinding of `JTable` just for that column and again resume its functionality for next columns.

```
table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
     .put(KeyStroke.g   etKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "UP");
table.getActionMap()
     .put("UP", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        //do something on JTable enter pressed
        }
      });
```

now I have use this code in if codition to disable the <kbd>up</kbd> key but as soon as the control comes out of if conditon i want the default behaviour of up key which is not happning

Comment: Override the listener

Comment: i have done that but its gets disable for all column not for particular one ..i have used INPUTMAP and ActionMap class for that

Comment: If you can provide some code, people might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Column and row sensitivity is a tricky thing with JTables; but it is queryable. `TableColumn` objects do not extend `Component`, so you cannot simply add an action listener to them. However, just adding this once:

```
new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        //Following line is untested code, but you get the idea:
        if(!Arrays.asList(table.getSelectedColumns()).contains([your column number]) {
            //perform up action
        }
    }
}
```

should do the job, and it's probably more efficient than adding and removing an anonymous class to your JTable. (To Swing/AWT, columns all look the same.)

Again I apologize for not testing this code personally, I'm on my way out the door for a two day trip. My core point is that your best option is to query the column in the `ActionListener` after the method is called, with a simple boolean test.

Comment: I have tried this but it giving similar problem like before my "column number is 1 " but up get disables for all columns

Comment: Interesting. Maybe I'm not fully understanding your question. An updated SSCCE would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using autocomplete in my JTable column

This implies that some component other that JTable has focus. Therefore you would add your custom Key Bindings to that component, not the JTable. Then those Key Bindings will have priority over the key bindings in the table.